# Finding a group of words using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I am using python to get user input and then by using regular expressions I want to check for certain words. In this case I want to check how the user is feeling and then store it in a list. The problem is that when I print the list it is empty.

```
import re

phrase = raw_input("How are you feeling ")

phrase = phrase.lower()
feel=(re.findall(r^(?=.*\bsad\b)(?=.*\bhappy\b)(?=.*\bjoyful\b)(?=.*\bmad\b)(?=.*\bsad\b), phrase))
print feel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a python expert, but am fairly decent with regex. Why wouldn't you just use something like:

```
\b(happy|sad|joyful|mad)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Add chars to match

```
  ...(?=.*\bsad\b).*
```